# Get the creation date of a Google or Gmail account

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

I scanned through the Google API library and it looks like there's no way to get the *date on which a Gmail address or Google account was created*.

Could you please add that? It will help identify fake accounts that people create just before signing up for your service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a website called [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) where you can [create an issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui), such as a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/concepts/issues#featurerequest).

> Before filing an issue, have a look if a similar feature request
>   exists already.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, see following solution from Reddit user [u/PaddyLandau](https://www.reddit.com/user/PaddyLandau/).

[From Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GMail/comments/188c5gx/instructions_how_to_find_when_you_created_your/?rdt=60284)

> 1. Go to [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/).
> 2. "Select data to include" > "Deselect all" (otherwise the download will potentially be gigantic and take at least a couple of days to get).
> 3. Scroll down to "Google Account" ("Data about registration and Account Activity") and select it.
> 4. Scroll to the end of the page and press "Next step".
> 5. Accept the defaults, or amend the settings if you prefer, and press "Create export". Note: If you're using Windows, choose .zip for the file type. For MacOS or Linux, choose either .zip or .tgz, whichever format you prefer.
> 6. Either stay on the page until the download becomes available (you might have to refresh the page; the download will be at the top of the page), or wait for the email notification to arrive. In my case, it took about one minute, so I expect it to be quick.
> 7. Press the download button, enter your password when prompted, and download the file. The file size is likely to be tiny; mine was under 50 KB despite my account being over a decade old.
> 8. The file is a compressed .zip or .tgz file. Open it, and you'll find a folder "Takeout"; in there, another folder "Google Account"; and in there, a file "username.SubscriberInfo.html". Open that file in your browser (double-click should suffice if you're using a mouse).
> 9. Near the top of the browser tab, you'll see "Created on". This gives the full date and time (note for Americans: The format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss). The time zone is Z (a.k.a. military time, i.e. UTC+0).

[A medium post for this solutions with screenshots](https://reetpriye.medium.com/how-to-know-the-creation-date-of-your-google-account-7d6073da5fb0)